# cannot retrieve data from firebase

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i keep getting this particular error.

> Can't convert object of type `java.lang.String` to type `com.example.alex.biometric_authenticated_memo.Memo`

how do i retrieve my data from the firebase

Comment: Please add your database structure and the relevant code.

Comment: To do perform any action with firebase you need to initialize firebase everytime and then create/follow node and Insert/retrive data.... For more details visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/.... And always try to ask question by posting some code snippet

Comment: can you add the code ?

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that

```
com.example.alex.biometric_authenticated_memo.Memo
```

is not a type of `java.lang.String`

You are trying to cast a String to your custom Memo class, which is not possible.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Your string could be a JSON object that can be converted to the object(Memo)